# Sybase ASE BulkCopy "The data type or the function is not supported" writing to a non-null user-defined type

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am having a problem migrating a `NUMERIC(8,0)` from Sql Server to a column in ASE (v16.0) which has a user-defined type of `NUMERIC(8,0)` .

I have simple user-defined type:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM systypes WHERE name='typ_small_id')
BEGIN
EXEC sp_droptype 'typ_small_id'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM systypes WHERE name='typ_small_id')
    PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING DATATYPE typ_small_id >>>'
ELSE
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED DATATYPE typ_small_id >>>'
END
go
EXEC sp_addtype 'typ_small_id','numeric(8,0)','NOT NULL'
go
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM systypes WHERE name='typ_small_id')
    PRINT '<<< CREATED DATATYPE typ_small_id >>>'
ELSE
    PRINT '<<< FAILED CREATING DATATYPE typ_small_id >>>'
go
```

This is used in a small table:

```
create TABLE dbo.target
(
    e_type_id     typ_small_id  /*NOT*/ NULL
)
```

I am trying to BulkCopy a single value from SqlServer using `AseBulkCopy.WriteToServer`. The source value is defined as `NUMERIC(8,0)` in SqlServer.
I am using the .net client for ASE and my app code is C# :

`public void BulkCopyFromSqlServer_t_sec_exchange(string sourceConnectionString, string targetConnectionString)
{
     SqlConnection sourceConnection = null;
     AseConnection targetConnection = new AseConnection(targetConnectionString);
     try
     {
          IDataReader dataSource;
          //The next method call returns a single row with a single column, defined as a NUMERIC (8,0) in SqlSvr.
          MssqlReader.GetDataReaderSelect_t_sec_exchange(out sourceConnection, out dataSource); 
          targetConnection.Open();
          AseBulkCopy blk = new AseBulkCopy(targetConnection, new AseBulkCopyOptions(), null);
          blk.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;
          blk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.target";
          blk.ColumnMappings.Clear(); 
          blk.WriteToServer(dataSource);
          blk.Close();
     }
     catch (AseException ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
          sourceConnection.Dispose();
          targetConnection.Dispose();
     }
}`

The value coming from SqlServer is 1.
This all works fine until I define `target.e_type_id` as `typ_small_id  NOT NULL` instead of being nullable.
When I do this I get an AseError:
`The data type or the function is not supported.`

Stack Trace:
   `at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopyBusinessBulk.TdsToAseDBType(TdsTypesDefines type, Int32 len, Int32 usertype, Boolean IsNullable, Int32& DateTimeLen)
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopyBusinessBulk.InitMetadata()
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopyBusinessBulk.InitFmtData()
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopyBusinessBulk.BulkOperation()
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopyBusinessBulk.RunInsertsRowsReader()
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
   at SybaseBulkCopy.SybaseCommand.BulkCopyFromSqlServer(String sourceConnectionString, String targetConnectionString) in c:..\SybaseCommand.cs:line 32`

When the column is defined as `typ_small_id  NOT NULL` the below queries both successfully insert data into the column from a query editor so it looks like an error in the WriteToServer code:

`insert into dbo.target (    e_type_id     )
SELECT top 1 cast(1 as numeric(8,0)) as e_type_id from source_tbl`

and

`insert into dbo.target (    e_type_id     )
SELECT top 1 cast(1 as int) as e_type_id from source_tbl`

Needless to say the customer's table has the column defined as not null (and cannot alter the schema) so I need to find out how to migrate the data into their ASE table.

Has any one seen this or found a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed by SAP (Sybase Tech Support) as a bug.